# MySQL error 1215 on table without foreign key

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, constraints, primary-key

I'm trying to create the database based on MySQL engine. But when it comes to process the following code:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `carrent`.`osPrawna` (
`NIP` CHAR(10) NOT NULL,
`REGON` CHAR(9) NULL,
`Nazwa` VARCHAR(100) NULL,
`Ulica` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
`Miasto` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
`KodPocztowy` CHAR(6) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`NIP`),
UNIQUE INDEX `NIP_UNIQUE` (`NIP` ASC))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

a 1215 error (cannot add foreign key constraint) appears, even if there is no foreign key in this table. Does anybody know any possible solution to my problem?

Comment: Are you sure this is the command which throws the error?

Comment: Yes, this is the instruction where MySQL Workbench returns error.

Answer (score 0):

You already declared your column NIP as PRIMARY KEY.
So this is already UNIQUE and you shall not add an additional UNIQUE INDEX on that column.

EDIT: Damn, I was to quick with my response. I tried it in my phpMyAdmin and I got no error. But nevertheless you should not declare it twice.

Comment: So maybe I should use PHPMyAdmin to create it.

Comment: This should not be the issue. I have workbench at work and can Test it for you